# C Infinite Pointer Loop (Caused By Duplicate Value?)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, duplicates, infinite-loop

Compiling with MinGW with `-O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99`

Well, this is what I think the problem is... Here's the breakdown:

I have a linked list that I built using

```
typedef struct Coordinate{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Coordinate *next;
} Coordinate;
```

I am adding "valid moves" (in the game Reversi/Othello) on a 6x6 board (matrix). My logic for checking whether or not a move is valid or not works just fine - it's adding things to the list that gets me into trouble.

For obvious reasons I want to avoid adding duplicate values to the list. However, every function I attempt to code (that seems like it should work) just crashes the application, segfaulting all the live long day.

So here's a function that I attempted to code:

```
int inList(Coordinate *list, int x, int y) {

    if (list == NULL) return 0;

    while (list != NULL) {
        if (list->x == x && list->y == y) return 1;
        else list = list->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and called it like:

```
Coordinate *validMoves = createNewCoordinate(-1, -1); // Just so that there is *something*

if (!inList(validMoves, 1, 1)) {
validMoves->next = createNewCoordinate(1, 1);
validMoves = validMoves->next;
}
```

So as far as I know, this should work perfectly. I've looked up examples online and all my really convoluted uses of pointers in this particular program have worked without a hitch thus far.

Anyway, **the real problem** is that if I **don't** prevent duplicates from being entered into the same list (connected through pointers), then I get an infinite loop (I imagine this is caused by two elements being considered *equal* because their non-pointer types are equal).

I've posted all three parts of the code on pastebin for full reference (no worries, open source, man!):
    [othello.c](http://pastebin.com/0rgYJfLX)
    [othello_engine.c](http://pastebin.com/TkPNythe)
    [othello_engine.h](http://pastebin.com/gfR3Fbii)

I've tried debugging but I'm not very good at that, I didn't really see anything worth mentioning. Can anyone explain what might be happening *and/or* give an example of how to avoid duplicates in a linked list? (I've tried so many ways my brain hurts)

**EDIT**: I do know for a fact that I am getting myself into a cyclical reference because of the following output when I traverse the list later (after multiple valid 'turns' in the game):

```
{1, 4} {3, 4} {1, 4} {3, 4} {1, 4} {3, 4}
```

I have no clue how `theList = theList->next = theList` (pseudo-correct) got in there, perhaps we're in the Matrix...

Comment: *"I've tried debugging but I'm not very good at that"* -- now is the time to up your game - you won't get very far as a programmer if you can't debug your code.

Comment: Yeah I know. I hate to complain and all, but it's 3 AM here, I've been awake since 6 AM, and I need to wake up again in 3 hours. I've also been staring at this code for the past 5 hours and have been stuck on this particular problem for about an hour. This is the point where I say that I really did try, and now I would like someone who really knows the language to help me understand why my system is failing ^^

Of course, I just started C a few days ago so cut me some slack ;P

Comment: Do you know the range of data or it can be anything?

Comment: It must be within the constraints of `0 <= value < size` where `size` is an even number `6 <= size <= 10`. Those really are just arbitrary values though (well, 0 isn't so arbitrary). However, for this particular case those values are constrained by other statements *before* `inList()` is called and/or `Coordinate`s are created.

Comment: Checking your `createNewCoordinate()` implementation, it malloc's memory and sets x and y, but never sets `next` to NULL. Thus you're leaving it an **indeterminate** pointer. When you use it, you're invoking undefined behavior, likely walking off the end of your list and into undefined behavior. Add `new->next = NULL;` to that function.

Comment: Did you set the `next` of your initial coordinate (-1,-1) to a `NULL`-Pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with how you add the new coordinate to the linked list.

`validMoves` is the pointer to the first `Coordinate` in your list of valid moves, so initially your linked list looks something like:

> validMoves -> [1st_move] -> [2nd_move] -> [3rd_move] -> ... -> [last_move]

And recall that these arrows come from the `next` pointers stored in the structs (for example, `[1st_move]`'s `next` pointer points to `[2nd_move]`, and `[last_move]`'s `next` pointer is `NULL`).

Now let's look at what happens when the code is run which adds the new coordinate to the list (specifically the line marked `2`):

```
if (!inList(validMoves, 1, 1)) {
validMoves->next = createNewCoordinate(1, 1); //2
validMoves = validMoves->next;
}
```

In line `2`, two things happen:

- `createNewCoordinate(1, 1)` allocates a new `Coordinate`, and then returns you a pointer to said `Coordinate`, with initial contents set to {1,1,NULL}.
- Then, the `next` pointer of the structure pointed to by `validMoves` (i.e. `[1st_move]`'s `next` pointer) is overwritten, and set to point to this {1,1,NULL} struct.

This leaves your linked list looking something like:

> validMoves -> [1st_move] -> [new struct with contents {1,1,NULL}]
>
> ??? -> [2nd_move] -> [3rd_move] -> ... -> [last_move]

`[1st_move]`'s `next` pointer, which used to point to `[2nd_move]`, now points to your newly made Coordinate, and now *nothing* points to `[2nd_move]`! So, the original linked list from `[2nd_move]` onwards has been orphaned.

**gdb** can be helpful in debugging such problems. A good starting point would be to add a breakpoint before the suspicious code area, put important variables on your **display** list (like `validMoves`, `validMoves->next`, `validMoves->next->next`), and then **step** through execution of the suspicious area and see if the printed values of the variables make sense at each step.

To fix this, we could walk the linked list to the end and then add the pointer to {1,1,NULL} there, but it is easier (and faster) to simply add the new `Coordinate` at the beginning of the list, but you will need a temp pointer variable, like so:

```
if (!inList(validMoves, 1, 1)) {
    Coordinate *temp = createNewCoordinate(1, 1);
    temp->next = validMoves; // the new Coordinate now becomes {1,1,&[1st_move]}
    validMoves = temp;
}
```

Now the newly added `Coordinate` is at the beginning of the list, the old `[1st_move]` has been moved to the second position, `[2nd_move]` to the third, and so on, as required (the linked list is in reverse order of the order they were added in, but I think the order of the elements does not matter in this use case).

---

Your stated application is for Othello. Why not allocate a contiguous array of `size`*`size` `char`s to store whether a position is a valid move or not, instead of using a linked list?

```
char * validmoves = malloc(size*size);
```

This only uses 1 byte of memory per board cell (which you can set to 1 or 0 to indicate whether the move is valid or not), and you don't need to walk a linked list to find out if a move already exists, just navigate to `validmoves[(row*size)+col]` and check if the byte is set or not; just remember to initialize the array before use.

Happy coding!

**EDIT:** In my above answer, I assumed your `createNewCoordinate` function initializes the value of the created struct's `next` pointer to `NULL`, but have now noticed that your implementation of it in othello_engine.c leaves it uninitialized. You probably *do* want to initialize it to `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the *extremely* detailed explanation of the problem! I kind of got myself lost in the amount of pointers I was dealing with. The problem was indeed in the `createNewCoordinate` function - not setting the `next` value of the new coordinate to `NULL` was the problem, and adding that one line fixed the seg faults and infinite loops! I now realize that though that I have a few off-by-one errors and need of more constraints in order to have the game be functional according to the rule set. But I can handle that no problem, thanks for the help Berry :)

Answer (score 1):

segmentation fault is usually a dereferenced pointer that is pointing to a bad location (possibly null). Add checks every time you use a pointer value (somthing like if ptr != NULL).

In your code I notice something that looks a bit wrong. When you find a new move to add you assign it:

```
validMovees->next = createNewCoordinate(x, y);
```

Then you make the list itsself point to the last node by calling:

```
validMoves = validMoves->next;
```

So now your list of validMoves is actually just containing one element (the last one) since it is pointing to the end of the list. You don't want to change validMoves pointer at all, this should always be the start of the list. Instead have another pointer that points to the end of the list, somthing like:

```
Coordinate *validMoves = createNewCoordinate(-1, -1); // Just so that there is *something*
Coordinate *listEnd = validMoves ;


if (!inList(validMoves, 1, 1)) {
listEnd->next = createNewCoordinate(1, 1);
listEnd = listEnd->next;
}
```

This may be causing you to infinitly add the same moves?? - not sure without seeing all of your code

----- EDIT -----

```
Coordinate *validMoves;
Coordinate *listEnd = validMoves;

if (!inList(validMoves, 1, 1))
{
    if (validMoves == NULL)
    {
        validMoves = createNewCoordinate(1, 1); // first time only
        listEnd = validMoves;
    }
    else
    {
        listEnd->next = createNewCoordinate(1, 1); // add new element to the end
        listEnd = listEnd->next; // Move listEnd to last element
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yeah.... and stick in lines of debug (printfs) so you can see where your program gets to :)

Comment: I do have plenty of lines of `printf`s, and in fact all my code is there in the question toward the bottom (via *pastebin*). I call the function like `listEnd->next = createNewCoordinate(int x, int y)` because there is a trash value that is the head of the list. If I remove that trash value (don't initialize the list) and attempt to create Coordinates using the `createNewCoordinate()` function, I end up with a seg fault. Honestly I have no idea why, I've tried manipulating this 10 different ways and I still keep getting seg faults :P

Comment: I don't see in your paste bin where function inList is called... But anyway, you don't want a trash value at the head of the list. Ideally create validMoves empty then for the first time check if validMoves == null if so assign createNewCoordinate(1, 1); to it. listEnd should always point to validMoves->next (except at the start where listEnd = validMoves.

Answer (score 1):

I asked you the data range, so that I can think of some other way to check the duplicate of data. If memory is not a constrained for you. You can do something like the following. This is a logic kind to check the duplicate data value. I have a simple look up table of data value, whose index and value is same and there is a count field. If the count field is zero that means unique value can come in. When you delete the data , subtract the count. This way you keep a track of count and ensure the uniqueness of the value. Since, it is an array no need to traverse also. A few additional code has to implemented for this management. But, It should be possible if well designed.

[image]

Comment: This would be a good plan of action for handling duplicates - I will try to revamp my code after I turn in the functioning program to my professor. Currently the list has/displays duplicate values but they are not causing any problems aside from being annoying to look at. Thanks for the suggestion :)